# Lagrangian Dual with Absolute Value constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, duality-theorems

Given the optimization problem below where $Q \in R^{n \times n}$:
$$ \min \ x^TQx + c^Tx \\ 
\mathbb{-1} \leq x \leq \mathbb{1}$$

The problem in standard form is:
$$\min \ f(x) \\
st \ Ax \leq b$$

where

$$A = \pmatrix{I_n \\ -I_n} \in R^{2n \times n}, \ b= \mathbb{1} \in R^{2n} \text{ and } f(x)=x^TQx + c^Tx$$

I need to show that the Lagragian dual problem is:
$$\underset{\lambda}{\max} \ -\frac{1}{2}(\lambda-c)^TQ^{-1}(\lambda-c) - \lVert \lambda \lVert _1$$

---

My attempt at the solution.

The dual function is:
$$g(x,\lambda)= \underset{x}{\min} x^TQx + c^Tx + \lambda^T(b-Ax)  \\
\Rightarrow \ 2Qx + c = A^T\lambda$$
This gives $x^*=\frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}(A^T\lambda-c)$

Plugging into the dual function:
$$g(x^*,\lambda) = [\frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}(A^T\lambda-c)^T]Q[\frac{1}{2}Q^{-1}(A^T\lambda-c)]+(\lambda^TA - c^T)*(\frac{1}{2}(A^T\lambda-c)Q^{-1} + \lambda^Tb \\
=-1/4(A^T\lambda-c)^TQ^{-1}(A^T\lambda-c) + \lambda^Tb$$

From this I get an incorrect Lagrangian dual problem:

$$\underset{x}{\min} f(x) \ st \ Ax \leq b = \underset{\lambda}{\max} -1/4(A^T\lambda-c)^TQ^{-1}(A^T\lambda-c) + \lambda^Tb$$

I'm not quite sure how to go from here since the $A^T\lambda$ does not simplify to $\lambda$ nor does the $\lambda^Tb$ simplify to the L1 norm. Was my approach completely wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if $x^*$ satisify $Ax \leq b$. How would you check? Also what would be the benefit to adding an extra variable $y$?

Comment: $A$ and $b$ aren't obvious in your original problem.  What are they?

Comment: @TaraP: I see that your dual function does not include multipliers for the constraints $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, unless this is what $A$ and $b$ are supposed to be there for.

Comment: It may be easier to add an extra variable $y$, the constraint $y=x$, and $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ (instead of $-1 \leq x \leq 1$). You can explicitly maximize over the extra dual variable this results in, which gives the 1-norm.

Comment: @LinAlg: I will try that thank you!

Comment: @VHarisop and Brian Borchers I updated the original problem.  Sorry it was not clear.